SVG-based HMI, how to link frontend with backend
I'm building a web based HMI (user interface) that shows some SVG objects that change their state according to data received from a python app. I simply need to change the color of the SVG objects if a function is ran in the backend.
For example:
<path style="fill:#5d5d5d;fill-opacity:1;stroke-width:0.264583" d="m 34.350404,74.999997 h 2.5" id="path13" />
In my python app, there would be a function like "update_path(pathID, color)" that changes the fill color of the path, something like update_path(path13, "#ffffff").
I'm not sure how to approach this, I've been looking at flask and fastapi but I have no web development experience and it's all a bit confusing. Do I use javascript and exchange data with the backend or I can simply update the web page directly? The flux of data is pretty high, there are multiple objects that update quite frequently.

if you want to change something on page without reloading all page then you have to use JavaScript. And in JavaScript it may need fetch(url, ...) to get information from server. And it may need to run in loop (using setInterval(function, milliseconds)) to check server every few seconds.

instead of fetch() you may try to use WebSockets but it also need to run code in JavaScript and it may need extension for FastAPI to works with WeSockets (normal Flask would need Flask-SocketIO)
